Unclear format of arguments in IOTableBackend.write method
In brightway2 I am trying to understand how to use the IOTableBackend.write method
the source code documentation says that:

products is a dictionary of product datasets in the normal format.


exchanges is a list of exchanges with the format (input code, output code, type, value)

I think the second is clear but the first is not. What is a "product dataset" and what is "normal format"? For example, this code returns an error.
import bw2data as bd

products = {('bedb', 'act1'): { 'name':'sadkj', 'unit': 'aaa'}, 
            ('bedb', 'act2'): { 'name':'askdj', 'unit': 'bbb'}}

exchanges = [('act1', 'act1', 'production', 1),
             ('act1', 'act2', 'technosphere', 0.567),
             ('act2', 'act2', 'production', 1), 
             ('act2', 'act1', 'technosphere', 0.601)]


bedb = bd.backends.iotable.IOTableBackend('bedb')

bedb.write(products, exchanges)

I have also tried using a dictionary that can be normally written as a brightway database without using the backend option, but that did not work either.
Can anybody specify what is the right format for both the "products" and "exchanges" arguments and provide an example?

I found this: https://docs.brightway.dev/en/legacy/_modules/bw2io/importers/exiobase3_hiot.html where the IO table is implemented so we can see how things should look like
products = {
    ("bedb", "act1"): {
        "name": "sadkj",
        "unit": "aaa",
        "location": "GLO",
        "type": "product",
        "format": "some_format",
        "key": ("bedb", "act1"),
    },
    ("bedb", "act2"): {
        "name": "askdj",
        "unit": "bbb",
        "location": "GLO",
        "type": "product",
        "format": "some_format",
        "key": ("bedb", "act2"),
    },
}

exchanges = [
    (("bedb", "act1"), ("bedb", "act1"), "production", 1),
    (("bedb", "act1"), ("bedb", "act2"), "technosphere", 0.567),
    (("bedb", "act2"), ("bedb", "act2"), "production", 1),
    (("bedb", "act2"), ("bedb", "act1"), "technosphere", 0.601),
]


Thank you. This works: the import goes through and bw writes the database. So this answered perfectly my query. I also added the biosphere exchanges to the exchanges object and can link to biosphere3 and perform calculations. All good. The strange thing is the results give no meaning. This should be a 2 x 2 tech matrix but when performing the analysis I can't reproduce any of the results that I can obtain from the same system in e.g. Excel. Not sure why.
